# Return SOLR result which has "x" field with value "v"

Tags: solr

I am using SOLR 4.9 Version.Following are my indexed document.

```
    {
       "id": "1",
       "index_id": "index",
       "tm_title":"Avenger"
       "category":"1"
       "type":"movie"
       "article_type":"Hollywood"
    },
    {
       "id": "2",
       "index_id": "index",
       "tm_title":"Avenger 2: Age of ultron"
       "category":"1",
       "type":"movie"
       "article_type":"Hollywood"
    },
    {
       "id": "3",
       "index_id": "index",
       "tm_title":"Spiderman"
       "category":"2"
       "type":"movie"
       "article_type":"Hollywood"
    },
    {
       "id": "4",
       "index_id": "index",
       "tm_title":"Emy Jackson"
       "type":"celebrity"
       "article_type":"Hollywood"
    },
    {
       "id": "5",
       "index_id": "index",
       "tm_title":"Jim Watson"
       "type":"celebrity"
       "article_type":"Hollywood"
    }
```

**Now requirement is like combination of movie and celebrity result like this.**

1. Query 1: If searching for **"Hollywood"** which have **"category":"2"** and also include celebrities. Then result will be ids of **3,4,5**.
2. Query 1: If searching for **"Hollywood"** which have **"category":"1"** and also include celebrities. Then result will be ids of **1,2,4,5**.

I searched a lot for this but not find out the solution for this.
I am trying following query.

FOR Query 1:

```
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=Hollywood&fq=if(exist(category),category:2,'');
```

FOR Query 2:

```
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=Hollywood&fq=if(exist(category),category:1,'');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AND operator

```
 localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=article_type:Hollywood AND category:2 AND type:celebrity
```

second query

```
localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=article_type:Hollywood AND category:1 AND type:celebrity
```

Comment: I used following query for combination of both     localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=Hollywood AND (category:1 OR category:2)

Comment: @user34613 thank you. u used combination of operators with single query, thats actually better than using two separate queries which gives same results.

Comment: hi I am facing one problem on above query, as if type double and or opening braces in query then query is not work. like "localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=hollywood (article_type:Hollywood AND category:1 AND type:celebrity
"

Comment: Or localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=hollywood and (article_type:Hollywood AND category:1 AND type:celebrity